# Read global variable that is continuously written

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

On the iPhone, we are taking images from the camera and saving them in a global `UIImage` property.  In another view controller class we are attempting to access this property in order to display the last one written (there is only ever one since it is rewritten).  We get a crash saying 'exe bad access' when we try to read the image.  We are guessing this means that the image is not done being written when we try to access it.

How can we work around this?  The nature of the project demands that this image be updated frequently and we will need to, after some user input, take that image and work with it.  We need access to it.

The one possible confounding bit of evidence is that we had the same error even after using an `NSTimer` to delay the image access by 10 seconds (just to diagnose the issue).  This is after stopping the camera session, so there should be no new input after that point.

---

More question info:

This is the function that receives the image from the camera on each frame. Every 8 frames, we save a copy to the global var and process the image.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection { 

    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        liveImageView.image = image;
        if (mod%8==0) {
            [self analyzeImage:image];
            currentImage = image;
            NSLog(@"retain count: %d", [currentImage retainCount]);
        }
    mod++;
    });

}
```

The var is a global property because an entirely separate class needs to be able to access it on command when the most current image is needed.

The retaincount log returns 2 mostly but sometimes 3. :/

Comment: Sounds like you may not be retaining the image, try enabling NSZombie. That said, I might change the overall design around a bit to avoid the global UIImage.

Comment: Why do you need to use a [global variable](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)? Are you using threads?

Comment: what it comes down to is we need a [minimal code sample](http://sscce.org/). For a guide on what to include in questions on SO (and elsewhere), read Jon Skeet's ["Writing the perfect question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: What is a global property? Is it a property (which always belongs to an instance and has setter methods) or a global variable (which does not belong to any instance and a bad choice for non-const object variables)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code that writes the image can set an `imageIsWritten` indicator (which is reset everytime a new write begins), and the other classes can simply wait until it's `true`. Then, the other classes can set an `imageIsBeingRead` indicator to prevent an overwrite (imagewriter must wait until `!imageIsBeingRead` before it can write). And maybe wrap the whole thing in some sort of controller class...There's a name for this technique (I'm pretty sure), I just can't recall now...

(This assumes a simple single-threaded app. I don't know about what sort of threading libraries or other tools are available on the iPhone, so that's something you may want to research for a less generic solution that may work better).

Comment: In a multi-threaded application, this is vulnerable to [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_conditions).

Comment: Or you can use the `@synchronized(theImageVar)` in the blocks of code to limit the access to the variable to one block at a time.

Comment: @outis: Good point. My answer obviously assumed a simple single-threaded app. I don't know much about threading/synchronization mechanisms on iPhone.

Comment: @lef2: I don't know anything about `@synchronized` but why not post a full answer?

Comment: A synchronized block by itself could lead to a deadlock. A synchronized block with a boolean flag can prevent this deadlock, but could lead to starvation (though this is unlikely). A semaphore (using an [`NSConditionLock`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSConditionLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

you accomplish this by using a locked reads/writes to the variable. how you use the data will depend on how you access it. it is often acceptable to:

```
ENTER_LOCK
UIImage* img = [[theStaticImage retain] autorelease];
EXIT_LOCK
return img;
```

but you'll have to change that if you want to mutate the data. of course, your writes would look something like this:

```
ENTER_LOCK
if (theStaticImage != theNewImage) {
  [theStaticImage autorelease];
  theStaticImage = [theNewImage retain];
}
EXIT_LOCK
```

if you want to mutate the data, then you need to give clients access to the lock or implement every mutation beyond the client's visibility.

Comment: `ENTER_LOCK/EXIT_LOCK` are of course pseudo-code, since there are so many ways to lock data, depending how you actually access the shared data.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your UIImage global property as **`atomic`** instead of **`nonatomic`** the property will always be fully *set* before its *getter* returns the value to you. It's simpler than a coded lock and -- if the lack of being fully written is indeed the issue -- it should solve your problem.

**Edited to add**: Mind you, this is only true if you `@synthesize` the property; if you write your own getter and setter then you'll need to do the manual lock.

*(Note: leaving `nonatomic` out of the the declaration makes the property `atomic` by default, but if you purposefully add `atomic` it will be clear upon later review that it was intentional.)*

Answer (score 0):

---

#### Note: This information has been moved into the question.

---

More question info:

This is the function that receives the image from the camera on each frame. Every 8 frames, we save a copy to the global var and process the image.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection { 

    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        liveImageView.image = image;
        if (mod%8==0) {
            [self analyzeImage:image];
            currentImage = image;
            NSLog(@"retain count: %d", [currentImage retainCount]);
        }
    mod++;
    });
 
}
```

The var is a global property because an entirely separate class needs to be able to access it on command when the most current image is needed.

The retaincount log returns 2 mostly but sometimes 3. :/

Comment: why are you running the image analyzation on the main thread? I'd recommond using another run loop thread for that stuff.

Comment: SO uses a Q&A format, rather than the thread format you find in forums. Clarifications & addl. info for the question should go in the question. Edit your question and add this info to it. Also, the indentation on the code sample isn't very readable. 4 spaces per indent level would be best here.

Comment: ... As for multiple objects needing to be able to access the image, that doesn't imply the image needs to be global. It can (and should) have owners, and one object can introduce it to others that need it (read about [capabilities and connectivity](http://www.erights.org/elib/capability/ode/ode-capabilities.html#begets) for more on the topic).

Answer (score 0):

If an object is deallocated, the results of any messages sent to it are garbage. Since the block is added to the main queue, it will be invoked in a later iteration of the event loop, after the image object has been deallocated when the [autorelease pool is drained](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-999965). You can't trust `retainCount` within the block.

In the current implementation, you must retain the object outside the GCD block, then release it within it.

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection { 

    UIImage *image = [[self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer] retain];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        liveImageView.image = image;
        if (mod%8==0) {
            [self analyzeImage:image];
            currentImage = image;
        }
        mod++;
        [image release];
    });
}
```

A better approach would be to give it to an appropriate object, so that the ownership concept will prevent the image from being discarded early. For example:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection { 
    self.recentCapture = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        liveImageView.image = self.recentCapture;
        if (mod%8==0) {
            [self analyzeImage:self.recentCapture];
            /* rather than the global 'currentImage' variable, 
               send a message to some other object informing 
               it the image is ready for processing. This will 
               introduce the image to the other object, no global 
               needed
             */
            ...
        }
        mod++;
    });
}
```